# JAVA: SparkConf cannot be converted to SparkContext

Tags: java, hadoop, apache-spark

I try to create a simple program using Spark in Java and I get this error:

> Error:(10, 57) java: incompatible types: org.apache.spark.SparkConf cannot be converted to org.apache.spark.SparkContext

My code:

```
package com.example.lab;
import org.apache.spark.SparkConf;
import org.apache.spark.api.java.JavaSparkContext;

public class Lab {
    public static void main(String[] args) {

            SparkConf config = new SparkConf();
            config.setMaster("local[*]").setAppName("Lab");
            JavaSparkContext jsc = new JavaSparkContext(config);
    }
}
```

I have a Windows 8.1 PC, running Java 1.8 and Spark v 2.3.0.

Why do I get this error?

Comment: the signature looks correct, but the error states that you wrote something like `SparkContext jsc = config;` Maybe you have some stale sources caches in your IDE?

Answer (score 1):

Don't use SparkContext. Since Spark 2.0, you should use SparkSession, which involves both SparkContext and SQLContext. So you should specify your configuration in this way with SparkSession:

```
SparkSession spark = SparkSession.builder()
  .config(config)
  .getOrCreate();
```

Or even simpler, you completely forget the SparkConfig object, by specifying the properties directly with the SparkSession.Builder object:

```
SparkSession spark = SparkSession.builder()
  .master("local[*]")
  .appName("Lab")
  .getOrCreate();
```

And of course, if you really want a SparkContext object, you can do it:

```
sparkSession.sparkContext();
```

Check out the [javadocs for the SparkSession class](http://spark.apache.org/docs/2.3.0/api/java/org/apache/spark/sql/SparkSession.html).

Hope it helps! :)

Comment: Hey Alvaro,

Thanks for your reply. I typed SparkSession but I get this error:

Error:(25, 13) java: cannot find symbol
  symbol:   class SparkSession
  location: class com.example.lab.Lab

It looks like it can't understand SparkSession.

Comment: Hey, how have you imported Spark in your project? Anyways, [check it out](https://github.com/spirom/learning-spark-with-java/blob/master/src/main/java/rdd/Basic.java). Take it as a reference on how to create a Spark application using the Java API. It looks like in the Java API you need to create a JavaSparkContext object from the SparkSession: `JavaSparkContext sc = new JavaSparkContext(spark.sparkContext());`. Please try it and tell me if it fixed the issue.